# Nopcommerce EvenPublisher.Update() not updating entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, scheduled-tasks, nopcommerce

I am working on my NopCommerce 2.40 . I have created my own Store Entity. I require some of the fields in this table to use in my ScheduleTask. i.e.

```
public class CampaignScheduler : ITask
    {
          public void Execute()
        {
         var stores=_storeService.GetStoresForMails();
         //Get stores Entries. Here it doesnt get latest entry after updating store.
         //But on Store edit view I can see the updated entries
        }
    }
```

My update store function is

```
public virtual void UpdateStore(Store store)
        {
            if (store == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException("store");

            _storeRepository.Update(store);

            _eventPublisher.EntityUpdated(store);


        }
```

What I am missing here. Anybody knows solution?